# Caesar Cipher in p5js

Tags: javascript, for-loop, p5.js, caesar-cipher

I'm a super noob, and I'm trying to make a Caesar cipher in p5js, so far I manage to code the UI, but now I'm stuck and don't really know how to move forward can someone please help?

I know I need to use for loops, but I can't figure out how?
I really appreciate all the help
Thanks

```
let inp;
let button;
let alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
//  Type here your plain or encryted message
  inp = createInput();
  inp.position(20, 30);
  inp.size(550, 200);
  
//  Encrypted / Decrypted message
  inp = createInput();
  inp.position(20, 340);
  inp.size(550, 200);
  
//   Key
  inp = createInput();
  inp.position(20, 280);
  inp.size(200, 20);
  
  button = createButton("Encrypt");
  button.position(370, 260);
  button.size(100, 50);
  // button.mousePressed(encrypt);
  
  button = createButton("Decrypt");
  button.position(475, 260);
  button.size(100, 50);
  // button.mousePressed(decrypt);
  
  noStroke();

  // button.mousePressed(drawName);
}

function draw() {
  background(0)
  
  text("Type here your plain or encryted message", 20, 20);
  text("Encrypted / Decrypted message", 20, 330);
  text("Key", 20, 270);
  fill(255)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the completed version: https://editor.p5js.org/Samathingamajig/sketches/7P5e__R8M

But I'll actually *explain* what I did so that you gain something from this.

### How a Caesar Cipher works:

1. Start with a seed value, and integer of how much to rotate the text
2. To encrypt, for each letter add the seed to the letter. i.e. A + 2 = C, B + 5 = G, etc.
3. To decrypt, for each letter subtract the seed from the letter. i.e. C - 2 = A, G - 5 = B, etc.

### Pseudo code:

```
function encrypt():
  initial text = (get initial text)
  output = "" // empty string
  offset (aka seed) = (get the seed, make sure its an integer) mod 26
  for each character in initial:
    if character is in the alphabet:
      index = (find the index of the character in the alphabet)
      outputIndex = (index + offset + 26 /* this 26 isn't needed, but it's there to make the decrypt be a simple copy + paste, you'll see */ ) mod 26 /* force between 0 and 25, inclusive */
      output += outputIndex to character
    else:
      output += initial character
  (set the output text field to the output)

function decrypt():
  initial text = (get initial text)
  output = "" // empty string
  offset (aka seed) = (get the seed, make sure its an integer)
  for each character in initial:
    if character is in the alphabet:
      index = (find the index of the character in the alphabet)
      outputIndex = (index - offset + 26 /* when subtracting the offset, the character could be a negative index */ ) mod 26 /* force between 0 and 25, inclusive */
      output += outputIndex to character
    else:
      output += initial character
  (set the output text field to the output)
```

### Some other changes to your code:

Some other changes I made to your code that are required for this are:

- Have a global array of all buttons, and a global array of all inputs. You kept overriding the value so there was only one reference at a time, so you weren't able to access the values in the encrypt and decrypt functions
- Changed the order of creating the inputs (text fields), so that they are defined vertically, this is good for when we push to the array
- Made the alphabet variable a string rather than an array, you can still do `indexOf()`, `includes()`, `alphabet[i]`, etc. with a string and the definition looks cleaner