# How do you put interactive text in a p5.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I'm trying to put interactive text inside of a p5.js canvas but can't figure out how. By interactive text, I mean text you can highlight and copy, like text on any HTML website. Is there a way to do that? If not, what's the best framework for coding applications that use interactive text as well as elements that are in p5.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P5's canvas is just that, a canvas. (More specifically a `<canvas>` element's rendering context). Think of it as one big, easy to edit, picture. And there's the problem, you cant highlight/copy text in a picture right. Same with canvas and `text()`. It just draws the text you supplied as an image to the canvas, so no actual text exists, just a bunch of image data, that when displayed, looks like like text. You might be better off using `createP()` or `createDiv()` for this one, which creates actual text that the browser can highlight/copy. Simply replace `text('bla bla bla')` with `createP('bla bla bla')`, then use css to position it, change the font, change the color. etc.

Comment: My problem with that is that the text won't be on top of the canvas. Are you saying it's completely impossible to put text on top of a canvas element?

Comment: @Bagel03 the createP, createDiv, etc. creates & returns a pointer to a [p5.Element](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element), so you don't have to use CSS to "position it, change the font, change the color. etc."

Comment: Yea your right, I see that you posted an answer which OP should look at too.

Answer (score 3):

[See this code](https://editor.p5js.org/Samathingamajig/sketches/7P5e__R8M) that I wrote for [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189794/caesar-cipher-in-p5js/64190674#64190674) (not a duplicate) (the code isn't doing exactly what I say below but it will give the general gist)

The simple answer: p5's `text()` is just drawing text to the canvas. You need to use the [`createP()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createP) function (or createDiv)

Example code:

```js
let myPTag;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(200);

  myPTag = createP("This here is some text");
  myPTag.position(200, 100);
}
```

[Click here to see this code in action](https://editor.p5js.org/Samathingamajig/sketches/uX3NbfLR_)

You don't need to use your own CSS for this, just use the `<element>.position(posX, posY);` function. To change the value of the text, just use `<element>.html(newTextString);`